# How to trunc date in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I must show qtd sale for a specified parameter date in paginated report..kindly guide with expressions and ideas

For example if my date is 19/05/2023 I must show sum of sales between 01/04/2023 and 19/05/2023.. the sales should be aggregated

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to add a lot more information. What have you tried so far? Show samples of data as text. What is the source of the data e.g. database. If from a database, which one. etc.. Please read the following article on how to improve your question otherwise it is likely to closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask